# Obtener las etiquetas de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Estoy haciendo un **API** que recibe un **JSON** y necesito obtener cuales son las etiquetas que estan dentro de ese **JSON**.

Este es un ejemplo del **JSON**:

```
[{
    "Notification": [{
        "Channel": 4,
        "Type": 1,
        "Means": [{
            "Number": 88888888,
            "Code": 506
        }],
        "Contents": {
            "Message": "This is a message",
            "Audio": "URL"
        }
    }]
}]
```

En este caso necesito obtener las etiquetas de *Contents* o sea, *Message* y *Audio*.

He intentado trabajar con un código como este:

```
f.Notification.forEach(e =>{
    console.log(e.Contents);
})
```

Pero ese me muestra todo y yo solo necesito la etiqueta... Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y que tal si cambias un poco tu código y lo dejas de esta manera:

```
f.Notification.forEach(e =>{
    for(var etiqueta in e.Contents)
        console.log(etiqueta);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esto

```
f.Notification.forEach(e => {
      console.log(Object.keys(e.Contents));
});
```